# Why would giving a widget a background color cause it to disappear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-gridlayout, android-background

This XML:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/verify_code_upc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000080" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUPC"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffcb05"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="5" />
```

...shows this:

[image]

But adding this:

```
android:background="#ffcb05"
```

...to the EditText causes the entire EditText to "disappear":

[image]

Why?

### UPDATE

If I give it an explicit width:

```
android:width="240dp"
```

...it *does* display:

[image]

Comment: you are wrapping the content when there is no content in an empty EditText field. Try setting your width to match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the color does not have a size. Color drawables do not have a specific size, so you have to give it one. Another alternative would be to use a drawable instead of a color.

Answer (score 1):

change your EditText to

`<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUPC"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffcb05"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:hint="Hint occupying space"
    android:layout_columnSpan="5" />`

or change the

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```